# Error with PyML build

Tags: python, macos, machine-learning, build-error, pyml

I'm looking to start a Machine Learning project, and I attempted to install PyML (on Mac OS X 10.6.8). In doing so I received the following error while running `python setup.py build`.

```
PyML/containers/ext/SparseDataSet_wrap.cpp: At global scope:
PyML/containers/ext/SparseDataSet_wrap.cpp:17658: fatal error: error writing to -: Broken pipe
compilation terminated.
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wstrict-prototypes" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
PyML/containers/ext/SparseDataSet_wrap.cpp: In static member function ‘static Type swig::traits_as<Type, swig::value_category>::as(PyObject*, bool) [with Type = float]’:
PyML/containers/ext/SparseDataSet_wrap.cpp:3341: warning: ‘v’ may be used uninitialized in this function
PyML/containers/ext/SparseDataSet_wrap.cpp: In static member function ‘static Type swig::traits_as<Type, swig::value_category>::as(PyObject*, bool) [with Type = int]’:
PyML/containers/ext/SparseDataSet_wrap.cpp:3341: warning: ‘v’ may be used uninitialized in this function
lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/BB/BB-0UcDKHzKgl2HboGzXqU+++TI/-Tmp-//ccf93ouC.out (No such file or directory)
error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

I followed the following tutorial for the install process:
http://pyml.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html

Any suggestions on what might be causing it and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the pre-requisites installed, such as numpy?

Comment: NumPy is installed. I also manually installed SWIG and SIP4 (which is the only suggestions I could find to fix ANY error related to PyML builds).

Comment: the only other thing I can think of is need to run it as "sudo python setup.py build". I'll try to install it and let you know if I get the same issue.

Comment: which version of python are you using?  I am encountering the same issue with 2.7.2 ...

Answer (score 1):

I also had precisely the same problem using PyML on Ubuntu.

Installing the Python development package (python2.x-dev) resolved the issue.  You need to install those Python development headers, installing XCode should also install the headers on Mac.

They are usually located in "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/"